# date format in oracle/mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Help me to populate below columns as date without using to_date or to_char functions.

| day | month | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1995 |
| 2 | 3 | 1998 |
| 5 | 6 | 2020 |

**output**

| date |
| --- |
| 01-02-1995 |
| 02-03-1998 |
| 05-06-2020 |

Comment: You'd better decide Oracle or MySQL, because the answers won't be the same.

Comment: preferably in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle, then concatenation of zero left-padded values might do the job (see line #7):

```
SQL> with test (day, month, year) as
  2    (select 1, 2, 1995 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 3, 1998 from dual
  4    )
  5  select day, month, year,
  6         --
  7         lpad(day, 2, '0') ||'-'|| lpad(month, 2, '0') || '-'|| year as result
  8  from test;

       DAY      MONTH       YEAR RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------
         1          2       1995 01-02-1995
         2          3       1998 02-03-1998

SQL>
```

Comment: This is not a `DATE` data-type; it is a string.

Comment: Of course it is, @MT0. That's what the OP said: " without using to_date or to_char functions." Code I posted does that. Do I like it? No.

Comment: No, it only looks like a date but it is really a string. Check [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/90XpE6Ry) to see that they are different types and if the OP is trying to insert the value into a table then this would rely on an implicit cast from a string to a date which can fail.

Comment: @MT0, three strings concatenated = a string (again; what else would it be?). The whole question/problem is wrong. If the result has to be a DATE datatype, then TO_DATE function is the most obvious choice (in my case, that would be `to_date(lpad(day, ... year, 'dd-mm-yyyy')` so - no problem. I have no idea why they don't want to use TO_DATE function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TO_DATE` as that is what it is designed for.

However, as an academic exercise, if you start with `DATE '0001-01-01'` and then use, for Oracle, `ADD_MONTHS` (or for MySQL, `TIMESTAMPADD`) for the years and months and addition for the days:

In Oracle:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       TO_DATE(year || '-' || month || '-' || day, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS dt,
       ADD_MONTHS(DATE '0001-01-01', 12 * (year - 1) + (month - 1)) + (day - 1) AS dt2
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(day, month, year) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 1995 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 1998 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 6, 2020 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DAY | MONTH | YEAR | DT | DT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1995 | 1995-02-01 00:00:00 | 1995-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 1998 | 1998-03-02 00:00:00 | 1998-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 6 | 2020 | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QrcuUcQr)

---

Or MySQL:

```
SELECT t.*,
       TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, 12 * (year - 1) + (month - 1), DATE '0001-01-01')
         + (day - 1) AS dt
FROM   table_name t
```

Which outputs:

| day | month | year | dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1995 | 19950201 |
| 2 | 3 | 1998 | 19980302 |
| 5 | 6 | 2020 | 20200605 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vKs2CJtQ)